# weakly equivalent mapping cones

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

Let $E\rightarrow B$ be a bundle with inner product. 
Let $D(E)$ and $S(E)$ denote the disk bundle and the sphere bundle, respectively.

Then $D(E)\rightarrow B$ and $S(E)\rightarrow B$ are fiber bundles with  fibers $D^n$ and $S^{n-1}$. Since $S(E)$ is weakly homotopy equivalent to $E-0$ and analogously for $D(E)$ we can concider following diagram:
[image]

where the horizontal arrows are inclusions. Now we can concider mapping cones on the both rows

$$ E-0\xrightarrow{j_1} E \xrightarrow{j_2} C(j_1)\xrightarrow{j_3} C(j_2)\rightarrow\ldots$$
$$ S(E)\xrightarrow{i_1} D(E) \xrightarrow{i_2} C(i_1)\xrightarrow{i_3} C(i_2)\rightarrow\ldots$$

Here is my question, can we conclude from above diagram that the mapping cones have weak equivalence, namely, that we have $C(i_k)\xrightarrow{\simeq} C(j_k)$ for all $k$?

Comment: This is true. It follows easily making some assumptions about the spaces involved. A thorough proof may be found in Appendix E of Martin Arowkitz's book "Introduction to Homotopy Theory".

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to find it :) one more question, probably it's trivial, but how do we know that $S(E)\rightarrow D(E)$ is the cofibration?

Comment: I'm not sure you need it to be, since you can always turn it into one by taking the mapping cylinder $M$ of the inclusion. However, it will then be a cofibration if $M$ is a retract of $D(E)\times I$, and I believe the proof of this can be done in more or less the same way as in the case of the inclusion $S^{n-1}\hookrightarrow D^n$.

Comment: I need to say that the quotient $D(E)/S(E)$ is weakly equivalent to the mapping cone. those two qustions compose this result, I hope.